# Missing Method MySQL2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, mysql2

Why would this method (list_id) be undefined when I have the adapter installed?

```
   ==  XXXXX: migrating ========================================
    -- create_table(:XXXX)
    -- list_id()
    rake aborted!
    An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:

    undefined method `list_id' for #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Mysql2Adapter:0x007f8345fc0f10>
    /Users/dcarpenter/Dropbox/workspace/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/migration.rb:385:in `block in method_missing'
```

HERE'S THE FULL LOAD:

```
     undefined method `list_id' for #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Mysql2Adapter:0x007f9a3d416340>
/Users/dcarpenter/Dropbox/workspace/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/migration.rb:385:in `block in method_missing'
/Users/dcarpenter/Dropbox/workspace/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/migration.rb:361:in `block in say_with_time'
/Users/dcarpenter/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/benchmark.rb:295:in `measure'
/Users/dcarpenter/Dropbox/workspace/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/migration.rb:361:in `say_with_time'
/Users/dcarpenter/Dropbox/workspace/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/migration.rb:381:in `method_missing'
/Users/dcarpenter/Dropbox/workspace/BlueFusion/db/migrate/20110812030512_create_outreach_campaigns.rb:4:in `block in up'
/Users/dcarpenter/Dropbox/workspace/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:157:in `create_table'
/Users/dcarpenter/Dropbox/workspace/gems/mysql2-0.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:421:in `create_table'
/Users/dcarpenter/Dropbox/workspace/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/migration.rb:385:in `block in method_missing'
/Users/dcarpenter/Dropbox/workspace/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/migration.rb:361:in `block in say_with_time'
/Users/dcarpenter/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/benchmark.rb:295:in `measure'
/Users/dcarpenter/Dropbox/workspace/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/migration.rb:361:in `say_with_time'
/Users/dcarpenter/Dropbox/workspace/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/migration.rb:381:in `method_missing'
/Users/dcarpenter/Dropbox/workspace/BlueFusion/db/migrate/20110812030512_create_outreach_campaigns.rb:3:in `up'
/Users/dcarpenter/Dropbox/workspace/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/migration.rb:314:in `block in migrate'
/Users/dcarpenter/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/benchmark.rb:295:in `measure'
/Users/dcarpenter/Dropbox/workspace/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/migration.rb:314:in `migrate'
/Users/dcarpenter/Dropbox/workspace/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/migration.rb:397:in `migrate'
/Users/dcarpenter/Dropbox/workspace/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/migration.rb:539:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
/Users/dcarpenter/Dropbox/workspace/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/migration.rb:615:in `call'
/Users/dcarpenter/Dropbox/workspace/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/migration.rb:615:in `ddl_transaction'
/Users/dcarpenter/Dropbox/workspace/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/migration.rb:538:in `block in migrate'
/Users/dcarpenter/Dropbox/workspace/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/migration.rb:525:in `each'
/Users/dcarpenter/Dropbox/workspace/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/migration.rb:525:in `migrate'
/Users/dcarpenter/Dropbox/workspace/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/migration.rb:435:in `up'
/Users/dcarpenter/Dropbox/workspace/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/migration.rb:417:in `migrate'
/Users/dcarpenter/Dropbox/workspace/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:142:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/dcarpenter/Dropbox/workspace/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
/Users/dcarpenter/Dropbox/workspace/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `block in execute'
/Users/dcarpenter/Dropbox/workspace/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
/Users/dcarpenter/Dropbox/workspace/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
/Users/dcarpenter/Dropbox/workspace/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/dcarpenter/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/dcarpenter/Dropbox/workspace/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/dcarpenter/Dropbox/workspace/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
/Users/dcarpenter/Dropbox/workspace/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:112:in `invoke_task'
/Users/dcarpenter/Dropbox/workspace/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:90:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/Users/dcarpenter/Dropbox/workspace/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:90:in `each'
/Users/dcarpenter/Dropbox/workspace/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:90:in `block in top_level'
/Users/dcarpenter/Dropbox/workspace/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:129:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/dcarpenter/Dropbox/workspace/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:84:in `top_level'
/Users/dcarpenter/Dropbox/workspace/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:62:in `block in run'
/Users/dcarpenter/Dropbox/workspace/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:129:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/dcarpenter/Dropbox/workspace/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:59:in `run'
/Users/dcarpenter/Dropbox/workspace/gems/rake-0.9.2/bin/rake:32:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/dcarpenter/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/Users/dcarpenter/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'



class CreateOutreachCampaigns < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :outreach_campaigns do |t|
      t.integer list_id
      t.integer parent_list_id
      t.integer survey_id
      t.integer user_id
      t.string short_desc
      t.string long_desc
      t.enum type, :limit => [:call,:walk]
      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index "outreach_campaigns", ["list_id"]
    add_index "outreach_campaigns", ["survey_id"]
    add_index "outreach_campaigns", ["parent_list_id"]
    add_index "outreach_campaigns", ["user_id"]
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :outreach_campaigns
  end
end
```

Comment: The first portion of the post is a snippet from the trace

Comment: I've added the full trace now.

Comment: It would be easier if you provided the source for the migration that's failing. Anyways, the error is on line 4 in the file /Users/dcarpenter/Dropbox/workspace/BlueFusion/db/migrate/20110812030512_create_outreach_campaigns.rb

Comment: Check the bottom of the full load section. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: I'm ramping on to an existing project and think it may be an issue with my setup. I'm new to rails

Comment: rake doesn't seem to be able to find the mysql2 gem code

Comment: btw, Ruby 1.9.1 has compatibility issues with Rails 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be `t.integer :list_id` on line 4. Rest of the lines have the same mistake.

Also note that the enum-column requires a [plugin](https://github.com/electronick/enum_column) and column called "type" is a bad idea because type is a reserved word, you can get around it, but you're better off renaming the column to something else.

Comment: Is there a case where that syntax would compile? i.e. the existing syntax?

Comment: Thank you. I was just thrown a new error -- create_table(:outreach_campaigns)
-- type()
rake aborted!

Comment: Theoretically yes. if list_id was a local variable or function that returns a string. such as `list_id = "list_id"; t.integer list_id`

Comment: As i noted before, type is not a good choice for a column name when using rails.